# exec with In Yii2

Tags: php, parallel-processing, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm working on a project using PHP and Yii2 framework. It has a task that requires making many requests to get data through API and it takes like one minute to finish. To avoid keeping the user waiting, I tried to use exec() function and redirect the output to other file. To make better UX

I tried this code in separated PHP files (outside Yii) and it work perfectly.

```
exec("php process.php > output.php 2>&1 & echo $!", $output);
```

once I tried to execute it in Yii using the following, it doesn't work.

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $url = Url::to(['user/dofile'], TRUE);
    exec("php $url > testoutput.php 2>&1 & echo $!", $output);
    return $this->render('index');
}
```

The error appears

```
Could not open input file: http://localhost/weez/frontend/web/index.php?r=user%2Fdofile
```

Is there a way to make it work in Yii actions?

Is there alternative ways to accomplish that

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute like `php $url` and expect php to parse it. try `curl -O $url`.

But a better option to supplement the original issue ("avoid keeping the user waiting"), try implement "queuing".

Comment: Thank you @jovani . Do you mean using queuing like RabbitMQ?

Comment: yup. but you may try to look at beanstalkd as well. :) @Nabeel